# Copy files in netbeans without copy them in version control (Mercurial, but I think with all VC systems)

Tags: git, svn, netbeans, mercurial

My project is under version control (Mercurial). I'm trying to copy files in NetBeans (usual copy paste in project files tree). But Netbeans not just copy files but also mark it as copy of  base file from version control. How this can be solved so it will be just new file for Mercurial?

Comment: All sorts of fun stuff happens when it comes to merging files created like that. I manually paste file content to a new files or copy files in terminal. I'd make more sense if nb would assume vc in project files tab and no vs in files tab, but I'm not sure there's a difference.

Comment: It will be also great if nb will have some hot-key for files paste, for example, press not ctrl-v, but ctrl-shift-v and file will be pasted without vc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to prevent `NetBeans` from doing this in the first place, but as a workaround, if you do copy a file and want to make mercurial ignore its origins prior to committing.
You can go to a command line and use:

```
hg forget FILENAME
```

You can then commit the file, along with other changes, from `NetBeans`.